# for loop not working - the outer loop not iterating

Tags: c, string, for-loop, comparison-operators

I want to make a program to reiterate through a string and get an overlapping (remove the first element of the parent string in each iteration) substring of 23 elements. I think the outer loop does not work. Please help me understand what's going on.

Here is the relevant part of the code I have used.

```
char *copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
strcpy(copy, seq);

printf("%s\n %d", copy, strlen(copy));  
char temp[26]= "";
int templen=0;
for (int k=0; k>length; k++)    
{   

    for (int i=0; i< 23; i++)   
    {
        templen = strlen(temp);         
        temp[templen]=copy[i];  
        templen++;                  
    } 

    temp[templen+1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    temp[0]='\0';
    copy++;
    printf("%s\n %d", copy, strlen(copy));  
}

free(seq);
```

Comment: It is simply a typo in the outer for loop, so voting to close this as a "simple typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int k=0; k>length; k++)
```

This type of code will give you either

1. infinite loop

or

2. non-hitting condition.

Here, this is point 2. Considering `length` having value >= 0, the condition check in `for` loop will become a Failure, so it'll not execute the loop body.

For case 1, If you initialize `k` with some value > that of `length`, you'll face the infinite loop, as the `k>length` will never become false then.

You should change your condition check to `for (int k=0; k < length; k++)`

Also, you should move `templen = strlen(temp);` outside inner `for`  loop, or, you can omit that statement itself and initialize `templen` to zero before the inner `for` loop. You already have `templen++;` in your code.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I got a seg fault error when I switched - that's why I got confused with the boolean expression in the beginning. Do you have any idea as to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: @DonglimPark can you give a little more info? which line?

Comment: @DonglimPark what;s the value of `length`? if it's less than `22`, `copy[i];` is out of bound access.

Comment: Never mind! When I moved the templen statement outside of the loop it solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have mistaken the condition statement if the `for` loop. You've given the condition as `k>length`.
As the condition is always false, the loop doesn't iterate. Change it to `for (int k=0; k<length; k++);`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the outer loop to:

```
for (int k=0; k<length; k++)
```

You have it the wrong way:

```
for (int k=0; k>length; k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Instead of

```
for (int k=0; k>length; k++)
```

it should be

```
for (int k=0; k<length; k++)
```